# Why the 15MB Size limit for bzImages

Tags: x86, u-boot, bios, uefi

I'm working with `bzImage` to boot a x86 version of my kernel in a virtual machine via U-Boot.

U-Boot set a size limitation for `bzImage`'s of 15Mb though.
[U-Boot git](https://source.denx.de/u-boot/u-boot/-/blob/master/arch/x86/include/asm/zimage.h)

I patched to size limitation to 45Mb to see what happens and it worked as expected. Until I bloated my kernel further...

```
Error: bzImage kernel too big! (size: 50786512, max: 47185920)
## Kernel loading failed ...
```

I tried to find some information where this limit comes from but couldn't find any exact source.
I did find some comment somewhere that it is a legacy option as some older x86 bios systems can only read 15Mb.

As I'm not expecting to work with older hardware does that mean I can safely ignore this or do I miss some important information here?